# Div (not sure if its div) automitcally resizes when I click anywhere on the page in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue in Chrome V18. If I click anywhere on the page, my gray login box automatically re-sizes.

Does anybody have any idea on what could be causing this issue?

EDIT: You will notice I get the following error:

> event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.

I have an exact code in another protected directory that is running 1.7.2 of jQuery; that is not the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `<br class="clear" />` with `<div class="clear"></div>`.

`<br />` is a special tag that has a height depending on your global font, so if you are going to have a functional tag like "clear:both" then div or other elements with 0 size can be a better idea.

PS. The message you have quoted is irrelevant, but this is a little information for you:

1. That is called a warning, not error.
2. Although it is pending to be deprecated, it is still working currently.

Comment: Thank you this was the issue.

Comment: Thank you sorry i wasn't aware how to do that. Done now :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove that break '`<br class="clear">`' tag, or replace with `<div class="clear"></div`

I hope It will work..

Answer (score 0):

Would be worthwhile learning how to use the clearfix method in your code:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Makes life very easy :)